# Cannot rm -rf using variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, console, rm

I am trying to write a BASH script which will delete recursively all files in a directory.

When I write in console `rm -rf /home/dir/dir/*`, it works great, but I can't do it using variables.

```bash
VAR="/home/dir/dir"
rm -rf "$VAR"/*
```

This code didn't work for me.

Update.
It is really really weird. I've tried to delete quotation marks, but it doesn't work.

Here is my whole file:

```
#### VARIABLES

LOGS_PATH="~/Документы/tellbot_work/tellbot-autotest/mega-test/Reports/Mega\ test"

#### End of variables


#### FUNCTIONS

delete_logs()
{
    rm -rf $LOGS_PATH/*
    echo "Logs from $LOGS_PATH were deleted"

}

#### End of functions

#### MAIN

delete_logs

#### End of main
```

In output it shows a right path to the files...

Comment: What error do you get?  What does `echo "$PATH"/*"` print?  Did you literally use `PATH` for your variable?

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use the system variable `PATH` here?

Comment: **1:** don't use `PATH`. **2:** *DO NOT* structure this so that it is EVER possible to have that variable empty, especially if you are executing it as root... **3:** What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for that. I`ve forgotten, that PATH is system variable. I've changed it.

Comment: I recognized some issues if the variable used contains the tilde to refer to the user's home directory. So for example `ls "~"` doesn't work. But you should be very carful if you do things like `rm -rf "$VAR"/*`. If `VAR` is empty, you know what happens...

Comment: Eliminate a whole class of problems by refusing to allow spaces in your working paths (`LOGS_PATH`). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the tilde-problem by just using variable home. 
So just write

```
LOGS_PATH="${HOME}/Документы/tellbot_work/tellbot-autotest/mega-test/Reports/Mega test"
```

instead of

```
LOGS_PATH="~/Документы/tellbot_work/tellbot-autotest/mega-test/Reports/Mega test"
```

and the command

```
rm -rf "$LOGS_PATH"/*
```

Should be usable again.

Answer (score 2):

1) Remove the `\` in front of the space inside the double quoted string. You don't need to escape spaces inside quotes. The `rm` command (or rather the shell during [expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)) is looking for paths that literally contain a backslash and a space, which is probably wrong.

2) The use of the variable needs to be quoted in order for contained spaces to not interfere with [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

3) The shell will fail to expand `*`, if the folder is empty (unless you set certain options). The `rm` command will then look for files that literally contain `*` and will fail, of course.

4) Don't quote `~`, if you want the shell to expand it to `${HOME}`. Or simply use `${HOME}` explicitly, because the shell's rules for handling `~` are a bit tricky.

Since you want to delete the contents of the folder anyway, you are better off using `find`:

```
LOGS_PATH="${HOME}/Документы/tellbot_work/tellbot-autotest/mega-test/Reports/Mega test"

find "${LOGS_PATH}" -depth -mindepth 1 -delete
```

- `-depth` will tell `find` to operate *depth first*, i.e. to "find" the content of a folder before "finding" the folder itself. This is necessary, because you want to delete the found results, which must be files or **empty** folders, so it must be done from the inside out.
- `-mindepth 1` will tell `find` to exclude the base directory from the result, so you don't delete the base directory
- `-delete` will tell `find` to delete the found paths.

Leave out `-delete` to only see the results, without deleting them. You may add `-print` to the end, to see which paths got deleted.